# Confused About Passing Color to Class (Java)

Tags: class, methods, colors

Trying to write a program in which if a user enters in a name that is "Randy" than Java would generate a random number between 0 to 255 (RGB). If the name is "Prius" than the color would be green only. From there I would pass that random number or the green color into my tank class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program4
{
public static void main(String[ ] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.print("Please enter in your name: ");
    String name = kb.nextLine();

    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase ("Randy"))
        {
            for (int i=1 ; i<= 3; i++)
                {
                int color2 = rand.nextInt(255);
                Color myColor = new Color (color2);
                Tank myTank = new Tank(myColor, 25);
                }
        }
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase ("Prius"))
        {
            Color myColor = new Color (0,255,0);
            Tank myTank = new Tank(myColor,25);
        }

    //create a new instance of a Tank, get its dimension
    Color myColor = new Color(255, 0, 255);
    Tank myTank = new Tank(myColor, 25);
    int dimension = myTank.getDimension();

    //create a new instance of a Landscape
    Landscape myLS = new Landscape();

    //tell the landscape to add the tank to itself
    myLS.addTank(myTank);

    //tell the tank to turn around
    myTank.turn("left");
    myTank.turn("left");

    //ask the landscape where is its green opening (as an int)
    Point greenPoint = myLS.getGreenOpening();
    int greenY = (int)greenPoint.getY();

    //tell the tank to keep moving as long as it is above the green opening
    while(myTank.getPositionY() + dimension < greenY)
        myTank.move();

    //turn left
    myTank.turn("left");

    //hopefully, move through the green wall
    for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
        myTank.move();

    Point orangePoint = myLS.getOrangeOpening();
    int orangeY = (int)orangePoint.getY();

    if (myTank.getPositionY() + dimension < orangeY)
        {
            myTank.turn("right");
            while (myTank.getPositionY() + dimension < orangeY)
            {
                myTank.move();
            }
            myTank.turn("left");
        }
    else
        {
            myTank.turn("left");
            while (myTank.getPositionY() + dimension > orangeY)
            {
                myTank.move();
            }
            myTank.turn("right");
        }
    for (int i=0 ; i<200 ; i++)
        myTank.move();

    Point targetLocation = myLS.getTargetLocation();
    int targetY = (int)targetLocation.getY();

    if (myTank.getPositionY() + dimension <targetY)
        {
            myTank.turn("right");
            while (myTank.getPositionY() + dimension < targetY + 30)
            {
                myTank.move();
            }
            myTank.turn("left");
        }
    else
        {
            myTank.turn("left");
            while (myTank.getPositionY() + dimension > targetY + 30)
            {
                myTank.move();
            }
            myTank.turn("right");
        }
    for (int i=0 ; i<500 ; i++)
        myTank.move();

   }
}
```

There is more to the program however, I just need help with the colors. The program compiles and works. The only problem is the random color and green is not being passed onto my tank class. The default tank color is purple.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Color myColor;
Tank myTank;

if(name.equalsIgnoreCase ("Randy"))
    {
        for (int i=1 ; i<= 3; i++)
            {
            int color2 = rand.nextInt(255);
            myColor = new Color (color2);
            myTank = new Tank(myColor, 25);
            }
    }
else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase ("Prius"))
    {
        myColor = new Color (0,255,0);
        myTank = new Tank(myColor,25);
    }
else
    {
        myColor = new Color(255, 0, 255);
        myTank = new Tank(myColor, 25);
    }
int dimension = myTank.getDimension();
```

Comment: I tried that, however, the last else wouldn't work because I have other code such as "int dimension = myTank.getDimension();" And if I were to do it your way I would get 28 errors saying it cannot find the myTank symbol.

Comment: changed it.. can you try this?? you get errors because you have initialized mytank inside the if-else block